# call a function defined inside self-invoking function

Tags: javascript

I have a self-invoking function to hold all my javascript code.
(like suggested by book)

Inside this function, i created a button, this button has
onclick="myfunction()" attribute set. like this:

```
(function() {
    var x = 4;
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.style.width = "100";
    btn.textContent = "click me";
    btn.id = "bid";
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', "myfunction()");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    function myfunction() {
       alert(x);
    } 

})();
```

But then when i click on created button, myfunction() can not be found. the message is:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myfunction

Then I moved myfunction() out like this:

```
(function() {
    var x = 4;
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.style.width = "100";
    btn.textContent = "click me";
    btn.id = "bid";
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', "myfunction()");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

})();

function myfunction() {
    alert(x);
}
```

Now it can find myfunction(), but the alerted x value is something like
[object HTMLSelectElement], not what i expected.

I am kind of confused about functions inside self-invoking functions.

Comment: *"I am kind of confused about functions inside self-invoking functions."* There is nothing really special about them. They don't have differently than functions defined elsewhere. The actual problem is that **HTML event attributes** are evaluated in global scope.

Answer (score 4):

Don't pass the function as a string, because it's eval'ed in a context where the function can't be found, simply do

```
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

Comment: Or `btn.onclick = myfunction;`.

Comment: There's also the problem of the scope of 'x'.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that was my first version, I wonder if there's still reason to mention the compatibility problems it would solve

Comment: @Mwr247 There's no problem of scope if the function is declared in the same scope as x, the IIFE closes over both.

Comment: @dystroy: No idea :) (meaning I don't have a strong opinion on that)

Comment: @dystroy Whoops, commented back when it was 'onclick'. It's good now =)

Comment: Thank you very much . I tried it, it works.
but why the function can be called in the second case? 
is there some deep stuff i didn't get a good grasp ? :)

Comment: @totally: In the second case the function is *global* and thus can be found by the inline event handler.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what your asking if you want to to use another function thats onload or something foo being the onload function.

```
     function foo(){ 
        some code here for foo function
        bar();
     }


     function bar() {
        some code here for bar function
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Export your function so that you can call it from the HTML.

```
(function() {
    var x = 4;
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.style.width = "100";
    btn.textContent = "click me";
    btn.id = "bid";
    btn.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    function myfunction() {
       alert(x);
    } 

    window.myfunction = myfunction;
})();
```

Comment: Why did you change `btn.setAttribute('onclick', "myfunction()");`?

Comment: Brain fade. I meant to change it to addEventListener, and forgot. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `"myfunction"` -> `myfunction`.